# Traefik Unable to get SSL Certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, traefik, toml

I followed this guide https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-reverse-proxy-tutorial-for-docker/ 
I started up traefik, but in the logs I'm getting the following error:

> "Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"mydomain.net\" :
>   unable to generate a certificate for the domains [mydomain.net]: acme:
>   Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[mydomain.net] error
>   presenting token: cloudflare: failed to create TXT record: error from
>   makeRequest: HTTP status 400: content
>   \"{\"success\":false,\"errors\":[{\"code\":81057,\"message\":\"The
>   record already exists.\"}],\"messages\":[],\"result\":null}\"\n",
>
> "Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"test.mydomain.net\" :
>   unable to generate a certificate for the domains [test.mydomain.net]:
>   acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[test.mydomain.net]
>   error presenting token: cloudflare: failed to create TXT record: error
>   from makeRequest: HTTP status 400: content
>   \"{\"success\":false,\"errors\":[{\"code\":81057,\"message\":\"The
>   record already exists.\"}],\"messages\":[],\"result\":null}\"\n"

I'm using Cloudflare for my Dynamic DNS, I have my @mydomain.net pointing to my Router IP. At first, I thought it wasn't able to create the txt records in Cloudflare, but I do see the TXT record: _acme-challenge, being created. What am I missing?

Update: So I think I'm getting closer, not getting the previous error, this time I'm getting a different error, if anyone can help. Not sure what is going on.

```
  level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"*.mydomain.net\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [*.mydomain.net]: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[my domain.net] time limit exceeded: last error: dial udp: lookup (serverhostname). on 127.0.0.11:53: server misbehaving\n"
```

Below is my Traefik.toml config

```
#debug = true

logLevel = "ERROR" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

# WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend and backend configurations 
#[web]
#address = ":8080"
#  [web.auth.basic]
#  usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"

[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  address = ":8080"
  usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
#    [entryPoints.https.auth.basic]
#    usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"  
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[file]
  directory = "/etc/traefik/rules/"
  watch = true

# Enable more detailed statistics.
[web.statistics]
# Number of recent errors logged.
recentErrors = 10

# Let's encrypt configuration
[acme]
email = "myemail address"
storage="/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true 
onDemand = false #create certificate when container is created
#onHostRule = true #disable for wildcard domains
# Use a HTTP-01 acme challenge rather than TLS-SNI-01 challenge
#[acme.httpChallenge] #does not work with wildcard domains, use dns challenge
#  entryPoint = "http" #does not work with wildcard domains
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "mydomain.net"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "*.mydomain.net"

# Connection to docker host system (docker.sock)
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.net"
watch = true
# This will hide all docker containers that don't have explicitly  
# set label to "enable"
exposedbydefault = false
```

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help? Is there any other information needed to help me debug the issue?

Comment: add your own domain in place of `mydomain.net`